# Build search without grant select permissions

Tags: sql, t-sql

Currently I am working on a small winforms project which should allow the user to search in a table with specific conditions. For example the user can search after location, name, date and he can also search with more than one keyword. Now I thought how I could write that, since I don't want to simply build a string on the client, since the user than need select permission on the table. I thought if thats possible with a stored procedure and grant the user permissions on that stored procedure. My table is called event and has the columns name, location, start date.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_searchForEvents @name VARCHAR(30), @location VARCHAR(20), @startDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM event WHERE ...
END
```

In the where clause should be only the variables which are not empty linked with AND.

Comment: This sounds like a good way to get SQL injected.  What would be wrong with just using a prepared statement in your app code, where the parameters come from the UI?  Users don't need select permissions, because your app would have them.

Comment: Search for dynamic SQL and learn about it and its flaws

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How to be safe that the user can't SQL inject?

Comment: Statements make it (almost) impossible for someone to SQL inject you.  Read about them to learn more.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and stored procedures are highly vendor specific. Please add a tag for the database product you are using

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Whats do you mean with statements? SELECT, INSERT,...? Can you give me an example of a safe satement?

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow for this.  What you are asking for is too broad.

Comment: This should work, but possibly you need to elevate the rights of the procedure. Have a look at [`EXECUTE AS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in that case.